# What does "big dough shall be divisible with union dues for all" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In George Carlin's book *Last Words*, he mentioned that his father had produced the following message during World War II.

> I pledge allegiance to the people of the United States of America and all the political crap for which they stand, big dough shall be divisible with union dues for all.

I know the words "big dough", "divisible", and "union dues", but I don't understand the usage of "big dough shall be divisible with union dues for all". What does that phrase mean?

Comment: Without knowing the kind of man the father was it's impossible to say what he meant. It seems to mean the wealth should be shared out and everyone should pay their union dues. Maybe it implies everyone should *join a union*. Maybe it suggests the wealth should be *used* to pay everyone's dues. That comma is unhelpful.

Comment: It's not very meaningful but I think Old Brixtonian is right; it's obviously a parody of the Pledge of Allegiance and the words are probably meant to sound like words in the real pledge, rather than conveying a clear meaning. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pledge_of_Allegiance

Comment: What @StuartF said. Specifically, it's parodying ***one Nation under God, indivisible, with liberty and justice for all*** from the "United States Flag Code".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a ***very*** context-specific parody, which few native Anglophones would fully appreciate anyway.

Comment: I'd parse *big dough shall be divisible* as meaning that wealth should be more evenly distributed throughout society. This could mean anything from just increasing taxes on the rich all the way to a full-out communist revolution.

Comment: Okay. Since it's a parody. Now I can interpret the message as **big dough shall be divisible, with union dues for all**. Then it's a classical Carlin comedy punchline structure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. Since it's a parody. Now I can interpret the message as **big dough shall be divisible, with union dues for all**. Then it's a classical Carlin comedy punchline structure. Thanks!